# How to display radio buttons vertically using bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have an exam system and I want show my options per line. I already tried using `display: block;` but it did not work. Here is my code below.

```html
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Add Question</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <form method="post" action="{{url('tests')}}">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Question') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <textarea style="border: none"
                            class="form-control{{ $errors->has('question') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="question"
                            placeholder="Enter Question Here">{{$questions->question}}</textarea>
                        @if ($errors->has('question'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('question') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: block"><br>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name="q" id="option1" style="w">{{$questions->option1}}
                    </span>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name="q" id="option1" style="w">{{$questions->option2}}
                    </span><span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name="q" id="option1" style="w">{{$questions->option3}}
                    </span><span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name="q" id="option1" style="w">{{$questions->option4}}
                    </span>
                </div>
```

and here is the output of the above code

[image: output of the example]

Comment: Change the `<span>` tags to `<div>` tags.

Comment: Span is an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'bootstrap' way to do this is to let bootstrap handle it. Per their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#layout):

> Since Bootstrap applies display: block and width: 100% to almost all our form controls, forms will by default stack vertically.

Meaning, by using the proper tags it automatically stacks vertically. Since `span` is an inline element it obviously will display as such. So, you need to use an element that is not inline like the example bootstrap [gives](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#default-stacked): `div`.

They have dedicated classes for situations like horizontal form elements.

The accepted answer is not a semantic-forward solution. When building websites you should *always* take semantics into account, for many reasons but mainly SEO and accessibility.

Bootstrap has great documentation and it will only benefit you to familiarize yourself with it. The following solution is taken directly from there:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-body">
      <form method="post">
        <h3>Question</h3>
        <div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="q" id="option1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="option1">Option 1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="q" id="option2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="option2">Option 2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" name="q" id="option3" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="option3">Option 3</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" name="q" id="option4" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="option4">Option 4</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Other key takeaways:

- `style="w"` is not standard, does this property work for you?
- all your radio buttons share the same id, this is not how ids work
- you should use labels for your radio inputs like in the snippet. This is good practice and will be easier to style as your needs change.

Answer (score 0):

Usallay there are many ways to do but to keep simple use break tag after every span element

```
<span></span> <br>
<span></span> <br>
```

with css:

div span 
       {
           display :block
       }

Comment: block elements [already cause line breaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Conceptual_differences), why complicate things? This will end up being hard to maintain as the requirements become more complex. Again, this isn't semantic friendly nor bootstrap friendly. And changing span to div doesn't change the category and the content model of the element (also in linked reference)

Answer (score -1):

Can you just put them in`<p>` tags?
Alternatively, I think a flexbox with vertical align might help

Comment: I didn’t downvote but providing an answer that contains ‘I think...might help’ is not really an answer and should be reserved for comments and discussion, as those kinds of answers don’t generally help future question seekers. Additionally, you should consider HTML semantics when providing answers.

Comment: @soul yea I can't comment because Stackoverflow

Comment: Yes I know, we all go through it :) You just have to answer questions appropriately and you’ll gain enough rep just fine. This answer is still not an appropriate use of the `<p>` tag semantically and encourages bad practices